# How to make a hover state "sticky"

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover

I'm using *nearly* pure css, (doing this in css only is *not* a requirement) background images and adjacent selectors for a page that presents unique human-readable textual information (via a div left side of page with the class name "default-text") when the user hovers over horizontally stacked images (on the right side of the page, where each image is uniquely classed with a sequentially suffixed classname, i.e., .hover1, .hover2, through .hover7).

If you load the page (in the jsfiddle link, below) and run the code, the page works. However, I'd like to enable a "sticky" hover state, one where when the user moves the cursor off the image the state for the image and the accompanying text remains in a hover state until either: mouse hovers another of the images OR a period of time lapses. Let's say 10 seconds.

#### For example; here's two rows of HTML for the images:

```
<div class="hover1"></div>
    <div class="hover1text hovertext">
        <h3>Best-in-Class BBQ</h3>
        <p>tons of text</p>
        <p>Lots more awesome text</p>
    </div>
<div class="hover2"></div>
     <div class="hover2text hovertext">
         <h3>Penetration and Vulnerability Tenderloin</h3>
          <p>More awesome text</p>
          <p>What you wanted</p>
      </div>
etc for the balance of the 7 items
```

#### A portion from my CSS:

```
.context-services .region-inner .field-name-body .float-right .hover1 {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67315586/buttons/1_off.png);
    transition: 0s background;
}
.context-services .region-inner .field-name-body .float-right .hover1:hover {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67315586/buttons/1_hover.png);
    transition: 0s background;
}
.context-services .region-inner .field-name-body .float-right .hover1 + .hover1text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0s all;
}
.context-services .region-inner .field-name-body .float-right .hover1:hover + .hover1text {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s all;
}
```

My jsfiddle.net for this is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Skrinak/y676Q/).

Any insight appreciated; thanks!

Comment: do you mind using javascript? pure css is little bit hard here...

Comment: [Herrington Darkholme](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2198656/herrington-darkholme) I agree. I just thought it was cool I could get so far in only css. I prefer a JS-based solution.

Comment: I think using addClass in jquery is a better solution. I'm trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my [fix](http://jsfiddle.net/y676Q/31/), sorry for no transition

```
(function ($) {

$('.hover1,.hover2,.hover3,.hover4,.hover5,.hover6,.hover7').hover(
function () {
    $('.default-text').hide();
    $(this).addClass('hoverd').siblings().removeClass('hoverd');
},
function(){
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.removeClass('hoverd');
        if (!self.siblings().hasClass('hoverd')){
            $('.default-text').show();
        }
    },1000);
});

}(jQuery));
```

the basic idea after this fix is that use class name instead of css hover 'event'.
Since in css you cannot tell whether the siblings of the target element has been hovered, I will recommend to make javascript to do the job.

First, I change :hover selctor to .hoverd. Then I tell jquery to add class 'hoverd' to the target and to remove that class from the siblings.
When the second argument of hover is the handler for mouseout, jquery wait for 1 second(for test I use a quick one), and then remove the class 'hoverd'. If users do not hover to other tabs, the default text will be shown.

I think I misspelled hovered...0.0, please don't mind

Comment: There's a so much to like in your response. I hope you don't mind my asking about the comma, its forcing both nested functions to execute?

Comment: hover method in jquery accepts two arguments, so the comma is just a separator. In simple, $('.selector').hover( function(){...}, function(){...});

Answer (score -2):

If you mean alt text its really easy. Look at his example: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test

So the code you will need to add is

```
alt="Smiley face"
```

Have fun

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, but I don't see where you get this idea. I've reviewed and added more context to my question. Also, I strongly recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) over W3Schools as a reference point.